# Excel VBA to fetch Xero report

Tags: excel, vba, web

This code works, but not consistently.  Often it fails on this line:

```
For Each objElement In htmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("td")
```

Here is the code:

```
    Dim AppIE
Dim htmlDoc
Dim nRow As Integer
Dim nColNum As Integer
Dim objElement
Dim nColCount As Integer
Set AppIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
AppIE.Visible = True 'login may be required
AppIE.Navigate myString 'from clipboard
While AppIE.Busy 'wait for IE to open
    DoEvents
Wend
While AppIE.ReadyState <> 4 'wait for login
    DoEvents
Wend
While AppIE.Busy 'pause put in by Donald
    DoEvents
Wend
Set htmlDoc = AppIE.Document
nRow = 0
nColCount = 0
nColNum = 0
For Each objElement In htmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("td")
    'If IsNull(objElement.classname) And IsNull(objElement.innertext) Then
    'Else
        If objElement.classname = "RowHeader2 MenuLeft" Then
            nColCount = nColCount + 1
            Cells(nRow, nColCount).Value = objElement.innertext
        Else
            If nColCount >= 1 Then
                nColNum = nColNum + 1
                Cells(nRow, nColNum).Value = objElement.innertext
                If nColNum = nColCount Then
                    nColNum = 0
                    nRow = nRow + 1
                End If
                If Len(objElement.classname) = 0 Then
                    nColNum = 0
                    nRow = nRow + 1
                End If
            Else
                nRow = nRow + 1
                Cells(nRow, 1).Value = objElement.innertext
            End If
        End If
    'End If
Next
AppIE.Visible = False
MsgBox "Done"
AppIE.Quit
Set AppIE = Nothing
```

Comment: When it fails, is it on the first element or some other element? What error code do you get?

Comment: Hi Rich.  When it fails, it fails immediately on the first element - no error is produced, it must be that it finds zero elements and exits the For loop immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to allow IE to complete the navigation to the Xero Report...?

```
    'wait for IE to complete the navigaiton to the Xero report ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n = 0
While n = 0
    For Each objElement In htmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("td")
        n = n + 1
    Next
    DoEvents
Wend
```

Comment: This isn't really my strongest part of VBA, but I was searching and it looks like before you try to get the elements, you might try using a loop that looks for both ready and state = 4.  So: While AppIE.Busy Or AppIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: wend